# How to make figcaptions follow the (unknown) width of the image in all browsers

Tags: css

I have an issue with figures and figcaptions when images have fluent and unknown width. 
Figures can contain images of all sizes. The figue should just expand to 100% of its container, and the image should be responsive. Images won't have height and width specified in the html.
Figcaptions should always follow the width of the images.

What I have works in Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox. In Firefox the captions expand 100% of the container.

Markup is this:

```
<figure class="image"><img src="..." alt="">
  <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Css:

```
figure {
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 1px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* For demo purposes */
  border: 2px solid green;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  color: #757575;
  caption-side: bottom;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf
}
```

There's a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qrsxyLp6/7/).

Comment: removing `display:table` will make it working on FF

Comment: Yes, but it destroys the captions in the other browsers. 
I kind of thought that there would be a standard way of using this figure element in html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Mozilla Adherence to Specs is Strict](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1068111#c0)

Mozilla conformity to the specs for `<caption>` extends to `display` properties. `display: table-caption` renders only if the tag is at the top and `caption-side: bottom` is overridden. See [Bugzilla 10680111](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1068111#c1).

#### Figure A

**Figcaption is at the top.**

> **<figure>**
>   **Removed:** `clear: both; min-width: 1px; table-layout: fixed;`
>   **Applied...:** `border-collapse: collapse;`

---

> **<figcaption>**
>   **Removed:** `width: 100%; caption-side: bottom;`
>   **Applied...:**

---

#### Figure B

**Figcaption is at the bottom.**

> **<figure>**
>   **Remove:** Same as Figure A
>   **Applied...:** [`max-width: min-content;`](http://thenewcode.com/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-Min-Content)
>
> ---
>
> **<figcaption>**
>   **Removed:** `display: table-caption; width: 100%; caption-side: bottom;`
>   **Applied...:** `border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;`

### Demo

```css
/* figure */
figure {
  display: table;
  height: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.A {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.B {
  max-width: -moz-min-content;
  max-width: -webkit-min-content;
  max-width: min-content;
}

/* img */
figure img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.A img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.B img {
  width: auto;
}

/*figcaption */
figcaption {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  color: #757575;
}

.A figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.B figcaption {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;  
}
```

```html
<figure class="A">
  <figcaption>Figure A. <i><small>figcaption with <code>display: table-caption</code> but no <code>caption-side: bottom</code></small></i> </figcaption>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/320/180/people" alt="">
</figure>

<figure class="B">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/320/180/people" alt="">
  <figcaption>Figure B. <i><small>figcaption at default. Note the border is wrapped around everything whilst in Fig.A it isn't.</small></i></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: It's not quite there yet. The thing is - sometimes the image is small, say 200px wide. With your code it stretches the image to fit 100% which is not pretty in this case.

Comment: Agreed, the issue is Mozilla's handling of `<figcaption>` and ATM it's utter crap review my answer at your convenience.